# In Altium Why My Square slot is shown round in Gerber?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, altium, manufacturing

[image: PCB Layout FIle Output]In Altium I have created a square slot in PCB then I create the gerber files.

In CAM, file's square slot is shown as round shape.

Can anyone explain why?

Also I have enabled the G85 command.

[image: Gerber Cam File Output]

Comment: Do you think your board shop has a square drill bit?

Comment: Yes But In Altium Gerber Files It Shown As Round

Comment: Sorry, the answer is "no". Your board shop does not have a square drill bit, and can not drill a square hole. That is why Altium shows the hole as round. You can put a square pad around a round hole or slot, but it's simply not physically possible to drill a square hole.

Comment: I suspect you have set the pad shape to rectangular, not the hole shape. A screen shot of the properties dialog for your slot would probably make this clear.

Comment: See The Screen Shot

Comment: A screen shot **of the properties dialog for your slot**. Should look something like this: https://i.imgur.com/4sQnV9K.png

Comment: I see now there is an option to specify a rectangular hole. That might be manufacturable if you are doing punched holes rather than drilled. That method is usually used for very low-cost boards, one-sided copper, phenolic material type designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined the square hole as drilled hole, it will be round. There is no such thing as square drills. In addition, the drill file only knows coordinates and radius.

In order to make square holes you have to create a square on a mechanical layer, often the same layer as the board outline milling layer.

You will also have to notify the manufacturer that you have cutouts. If the manufacturer has an automated system, you will have to mark the cutouts yourself. (eg: Eurocircuits)